# How to install new module in opnERP7?

Tags: odoo, prestashop

I've downloaded a module at https://launchpad.net/openerp-prestashop-sync (which is used to synch the data between prestashop and openERP) and tried to install in openERP7. But it is not working properly.

Also, I would like to give you more details on my requirement:

My Requirement is – we need a addon to sync the data between openERP and prestashop hence i google and found a URL at https://launchpad.net/openerp-prestashop-sync and also downloaded a “techreceptives-openerp_prestashop_sync-670b2669c27b.zip” file.

After that, downloaded openerp i.e. openerp-allinone-setup-6.0-latest.exe and installed the same in my windows machine.

To add new module/addon into openERP, i’ve created new folder as “openerp_prestashop_sync” under “Server\server\openerp\addons” and then extracted the source files from zip i.e. techreceptives-openerp_prestashop_sync-670b2669c27b.zip. After this setup, i’ve restarted the service of openERP. But it is showing error message as "No handler found".

My question is:
1. How to install new module/addon into openERP to function without issues?
2. Is there any steps to follow while setup new module? If so, kindly provide the same. It would be more helpful to me.
3. In openERP – Is there specific web service for 1). product import and export 2. sales orders.

Can anyone please help me to sync the data between both systems (openERP vs prestashop) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Current Developments are on : [Bitbucket: openerp-prestashop-connector](https://bitbucket.org/techreceptives/openerp_prestashop_sync)
Also it is for `openerp6.1` .

Comment: Hi Ruchir,
Thanks for the information. Is this module work with the openERP6.0?

Have you tried before with openERP6.0? I need a solution to sync the data between both systems. If possible, can you please provide more detailed guidance. It would be more helpful me.

Comment: I think not sure but launchpad one is working with 6.0 and bitbucket one is working with 6.1 ..